# How to fix SQLAlchemy IntegrityError when trying to fix "Cannot get OAuth token without an associated user" error in Flask-Dance

Tags: python, flask, google-oauth, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-dance

For my web application, I'm using Flask-Dance to have users create their account by only logging into their Google accounts (I don't want them to have to make any new usernames or passwords). When I first tried doing this, I ran into the error:

```
Cannot get OAuth token without an associated user
```

I found another post that dealt with this issue (Link to it: [flask_dance: Cannot get OAuth token without an associated user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47643448/flask-dance-cannot-get-oauth-token-without-an-associated-user/48718671#48718671)). The #3 part of the answer is what I'm trying to do, but as I'm trying to "manually create the user account and associate it with the OAuth token," I'm getting the following error from SQLAlchemy:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) datatype mismatch
```

I'm almost sure that this is coming from the token. I have no clue why it won't accept the token I'm passing to it. If I'm able to resolve this error, I think the code will manually create the user account and associate it with the OAuth token, and then I can get rid of (as the other post says I should):

"user_required=False" in the line:

```
google_blueprint.backend = SQLAlchemyBackend(OAuth, db.session, user=current_user, user_required=False)
```

Right now I need help fixing the error with the database, but if you see any other potential errors that would be very helpful. I'm new to web development as I'm trying to teach myself this process. Since this error can be rooted from anywhere in my code, I'm attaching my python file below.

```
import os
import json
import datetime
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for
from flask_dance.contrib.google import make_google_blueprint, google
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import UserMixin, current_user, LoginManager, login_required, login_user, logout_user
from flask_dance.consumer.backend.sqla import OAuthConsumerMixin, SQLAlchemyBackend
from flask_dance.consumer import oauth_authorized
from sqlalchemy.orm.exc import NoResultFound

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'thisissupposedtobeasecret'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////Users/kentjo/Documents/git/CareerDay/login.db'

os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = '1'
os.environ["OAUTHLIB_RELAX_TOKEN_SCOPE"] = '1'

google_blueprint = make_google_blueprint(
    client_id='#removed for security of this post#', 
    client_secret='#removed for security of this post#',
    scope=['profile', 'email'],
    offline=True   #added in 
)

app.register_blueprint(google_blueprint, url_prefix='/google_login')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=False)
    time_stamp = db.Column(db.String(25), unique=False)
    first_choice = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=False)
    second_choice = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=False)
    third_choice = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=False)
    fourth_choice = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=False)
    fifth_choice = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=False)
    submitted = db.Column(db.Boolean, unique=False, default=True)

class OAuth(OAuthConsumerMixin, db.Model):
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(User.id))
    user = db.relationship(User)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

google_blueprint.backend = SQLAlchemyBackend(OAuth, db.session, user=current_user, user_required=False) #Eventually need to remove user_required=False

@app.route('/google')
def google_login():

    if not google.authorized:
        return redirect(url_for('google.login'))

    account_info = google.get('/plus/v1/people/me')

    account_info_json = account_info.json()
    json_str = json.dumps(account_info_json)

    email = json.loads(json.dumps(json.loads(json_str)['emails']))[0]['value']

    return '<h1>Your email is {}'.format(email)


@oauth_authorized.connect_via(google_blueprint)
def google_logged_in(blueprint, token):

    account_info = blueprint.session.get('/plus/v1/people/me') 

    if account_info.ok:
        account_info_json = account_info.json()

        json_str = json.dumps(account_info_json)

        google_email=json.loads(json.dumps(json.loads(json_str)['emails']))[0]['value']
        google_first_name=json.loads(json.dumps(json.loads(json_str)['name']))['givenName']
        google_last_name=json.loads(json.dumps(json.loads(json_str)['name']))['familyName']

        google_id=json.loads(json.dumps(json.loads(json_str)['id']))

        query = User.query.filter_by(email=google_email)

        try:
            user = query.one()
            print("FOUND USER")
        except NoResultFound:
            print("NO USER FOUND: proceed to create")
            user = User(
                email=google_email,
                first_name=google_first_name,
                last_name=google_last_name
            )
            oauth = OAuth(
                id=google_id,
                provider=blueprint.name,
                created_at=datetime.datetime.now(),
                token=token,  #PROBLEM COMING FROM HERE
                user_id=user.id
            )
            oauth.user = user
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.add(oauth)
            db.session.commit()

        login_user(user)

        return False

@app.route('/')
@login_required
def index():
    return '<h1>You are logged in as {}'.format(current_user.email)

@app.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Can you check the data type of the `token` object, and make sure it's what you expect? You can compare your code to the [flask-dance-google-sqla](https://github.com/singingwolfboy/flask-dance-google-sqla/blob/master/app/oauth.py) sample code, and see what is different.